# Fastest way to mix arrays in numpy?

Tags: python, arrays, performance, numpy

```
a= array([1,3,5,7,9])
b= array([2,4,6,8,10])
```

I want to mix pair of arrays so that their sequences insert element by element
Example: using a and b, it should result into

```
c= array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10])
```

I need to do that using pairs of long arrays (more than one hundred elements) on thousand of sequences. Any smarter ideas than pickling element by element on each array?
thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
c = np.empty(len(a)+len(b), dtype=a.dtype)
c[::2] = a
c[1::2] = b
```

(That assumes `a` and `b` have the same dtype.)

You asked for the fastest, so here's a timing comparison (`vstack`, `ravel` and `empty` are all numpy functions):

```
In [40]: a = np.random.randint(0, 10, size=150)

In [41]: b = np.random.randint(0, 10, size=150)

In [42]: %timeit vstack((a,b)).T.flatten()
100000 loops, best of 3: 5.6 µs per loop

In [43]: %timeit ravel([a, b], order='F')
100000 loops, best of 3: 3.1 µs per loop

In [44]: %timeit c = empty(len(a)+len(b), dtype=a.dtype); c[::2] = a; c[1::2] = b
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.94 µs per loop
```

With `vstack((a,b)).T.flatten()`, `a` and `b` are copied to create `vstack((a,b))`, and then the data is copied again by the `flatten()` method.

`ravel([a, b], order='F')` is implemented as `asarray([a, b]).ravel(order)`, which requires copying `a` and `b`, and then copying the result to create an array with `order='F'`.  (If you do just `ravel([a, b])`, it is about the same speed as my answer, because it doesn't have to copy the data again.  Unfortunately, `order='F'` is needed to get the alternating pattern.)

So the other two methods copy the data twice.  In my version, each array is copied once.

Comment: I added some notes that might help your intuition.

Answer (score 3):

This'll do it:

```
vstack((a,b)).T.flatten()

array([ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10])
```

Answer (score 3):

Using [`numpy.ravel`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ravel.html):

```
>>> np.ravel([a, b], order='F')
array([ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10])
```

Comment: thanks a lot falsetru, i was doing the job to thank and conclude on your proposal! Result is not intuitive, I wouldn't have bet on f2!

Comment: @unutbu, Thank you for pointing that out. removed my useless benchmark result.

Comment: @sol, If you want fastest one, see Warren Weckesser's answer. Actually, mine is getting slower quickly as the size of the array grow.

Comment: some ideas why? it will result in a nice discussion tomorrow at my work. ty all of you! I will test them on real data tomorrow.